# Rails - run pusher in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pusher

I use Pusher in my Rails-4 application.

The problem is that sometimes the connection is slow, so the execution of the code becomes slower.
I also get from time to time the following error:

```
Pusher::HTTPError: execution expired (HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError)
```

I send signals via Pusher with this code:

```
Pusher[channel].trigger!(event, msg)
```

I would like to execute it in background, so if an exception is thrown it will not break the flow of my app, and neither slow it down.
I tried to wrap the call with `begin ... rescue` but it didn't solve the exception problem. Of course even if it would, it wouldn't solve the slow-down problem i want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Information on performing asynchronous triggers can be found here:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem#asynchronous-requests

This also provides you within information on catching/handling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I implemented this solution:

```
Thread.new do
  begin
    Pusher[channel].trigger!(ch, ev, msg)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
  rescue Pusher::Error => e
    Rails.logger.error "Pusher error: #{e.message}"
  end
end
```